# Apache camel get value from body()

Tags: java, multithreading, csv, apache-camel

This is my camel main class, and my camel route

```
public class MyCamelRoute {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        try {
            context.addRoutes(new CSVRoute());
            context.start();
            Thread.sleep(20000);
            context.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class CSVRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    public void configure() throws Exception {
        CsvDataFormat csv = new CsvDataFormat();
        from("file:my_csv.csv&noop=true")
        .split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming()
        .unmarshal(csv)
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, body().toString());
    }
}
```

When running it, I get sort of what I expect which is

> 13:30:42.730 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - file://my_csv.csv] INFO route1 - simple{[[534488]]}
>
> 13:30:42.732 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - file://my_csv.csv] INFO route1 - simple{[[969034]]}
>
> 13:30:42.734 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - file://my_csv.csv] INFO route1 - simple{[[510711]]}
>
> 13:30:42.736 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - file://my_csv.csv] INFO route1 - simple{[[778410]]}
>
> 13:30:42.737 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - file://my_csv.csv] INFO route1 - simple{[[803306]]}
>
> 13:30:42.739 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - file://my_csv.csv] INFO route1 - simple{[[567892]]}
>
> 13:30:42.741 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - file://my_csv.csv] INFO route1 - simple{[[269041]]}
>
> 13:30:42.743 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - file://my_csv.csv] INFO route1 - simple{[[622768]]}
>
> 13:30:42.745 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - file://my_csv.csv] INFO route1 - simple{[[701100]]}
>
> 13:30:42.746 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - file://my_csv.csv] INFO route1 - simple{[[169439]]}
>
> 13:30:42.747 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - file://my_csv.csv] INFO route1 - simple{[[435246]]}

My question is, I want to access the value inside of simple{[[*value*]]} but I'm not entirely sure how.

What I have done previously is just send it to a process and use `exchange.getBody().getIn()` and check/cast it from there, but I wanted to try to avoid using a process.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To log the message body you must use

```
.log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "${body}");
```

And as INFO is default its quicker to do

```
.log("${body}");
```

And you can write a text also

```
.log("The message contains: ${body}");
```